# Caching the ids or the whole list results in Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching

I am writing an Asp.Net MVC app where the user can navigate to user profile page, comments page etc.
These pages has data in the form of lists i.e `List<Person>`, `List<profiledata>` etc.

I am currently caching the whole lists with userid as the key ,between the page navigation.
Is it considered a better approach or do i need to just cache the inner ids of Lists and re hydrate the lists from the database ?

At one time i can have 1000s of users online and that means i will be storing 1000 lists in cache !
I am using Entity Framework ,SqlServer and Asp.net MVC 4.

Answer (score 0):

one of the paradigms behind mvc is the idea of being stateless. Therefore storing things in cache should be avoided until it is necessary (perhaps for performance reasons). Here is a pretty thorough article on aps.net mvc caching that may help: http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9781449320317/ch_Caching.html

Comment: Thanks for the link,i initially coded like you mentioned but after reading many articles including how stackoverflow does caching, i have incorporated caching in many areas and i can see now my website is much faster than before.

Comment: Who doesn't recommend caching in ASP.NET MVC? Caching can be absolutely critical to performance. Stackoverflow (written in ASP.NET MVC) caches _everything_: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69164/does-stack-overflow-use-caching-and-if-so-how

Comment: @mfanto you are correct, there are very real uses for caching... I was trying to say that it should be avoided until it's necessary. I've updated my answer accordingly.